# IOS8 Blur Doesn't work on iPad retina simulator

Tags: ios8, xcode6

Visual Effect View With Blur Doesn't work on iPad retina simulator. It does work with iPad air simulator. I am using Xcode 6.0; IOS8

Seems like an apple issue to me. Do you agree? Notice that Image is just transparent not blurred.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

iPad Retina is 3rd generation iPad, which Apple has chosen not to have blur on, like iPad 2. This happened somewhere between the iOS 7.0 betas, presumably due to low performant GPU. It is the same with iOS 8.0/8.1. Use the Air simulator for blur effects. Notice that it is also 64-bit, so your code may behave slightly different depending on what you are doing.

Comment: so how should we handle this?

Comment: @CharltonProvatas What do you want to handle? Apple doesn't support blur on these devices. Instead, effect views appear as transparent grey view, like in the rest of the system.

Comment: In my case, the gray view does not look good in place of the blur effect, so I wondering how we would know how to check if the blur is not there but I think I have found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557090/blur-effect-showing-in-simulator-but-not-on-the-iphone           thank you

Comment: @CharltonProvatas That is for accessibility (user turned off blur). You need to check if it works in this case.

Comment: I see now, I have just noticed the issue now on iPad 2 whether accessibility is turned off or not.  Do you know if we can check UIDevice.current to see if they are using iPad 2 or 3rd generation or not?